# Reduction of Asymptotic time Complexity of a Loop Based Code

Tags: loops

I want to reduce the asymptotic time complexity of the code below.

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    if(c[i] > 2)
        enter code here
    {
        for(j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            c[i] += c[i] * d[j];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is impossible to give any opinion without seeing complete and fully-working code and, also, a mathematical explanation of what it does (to save us having to decipher your code). Failing that, you may just have to rely on compiler optimisation. Most compilers are pretty good at strength reduction.

Comment: Thank you Mick. Can you please give me a direction that how pipeline strategy can be implemented through program code.

Comment: Improved wording; cleaned up indentation.

Answer (score 0):

First, I have no idea what else might appear at "enter code here"; I hope you simply forgot to remove that from your source code when you posted.

The most obvious change is the awkward code in the innermost loop.  You access the **d** array up to **i** times, recomputing an effect that doesn't change.  Move that before the first loop, doing it once only:

```
d_factor = 1
for(j=0; j<n; j++)
    d_factor += d_factor * d[j]

for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    if(c[i] > 2)
        c[i] *= d_factor
}
```

This should greatly simplify your remaining problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. Please let me know how pipeline strategy of computer architecture or parallel processing of code can be implemented through programming.

Comment: That would a tutorial beyond the scope of Stack Overflow.